# sqlcmd output to log file for stored procedure execution

Tags: sql-server, linux, stdout, sqlcmd

Trying to run this below command from a Linux box,

```
sqlcmd -S<server> -d<db> -U<login> -P<pwd> -i /scripts/StoredProcedure1.sql -o /logs/output.log
```

If the SP is executed in SSMS it would normally give

```
Commands completed successfully.
Completion time: 2022-06-12T18:28:18.4580782-04:00
```

However this is not getting captured in the output.log as it is only of zero bytes.

How do I capture that output too.

Tried these, different combinations

1. -r[0 | 1] (msgs to stderr) - and it did not worked
2. -m error_level - and it did not worked
3. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html - and it did not worked

May be i'm missing something silly or just putting in wrong combination. Could anyone help here.

Comment: Unless I 'm mistaken that's not output (from SQL server) that's output from SSMS.

Comment: Yes, but how to capture the results or validate the SP execution using SQLCMD.

Comment: It's not *output* as such, it's just SSMS telling you that there was no further output and the query finished. You can just append it to the log file yourself if you want

Comment: Generally you either capture rows affected ... or you follow the principle that no error means success.